# Overlapping Sidebar in Beamer Template

Tags: beamer, positioning

I'm trying to position two logos (one logo and the titlegraphics) and a overlapping sidebar (graphical element)

I used negative `\vskip` `\hskip` for the top left logo and `\vspace` for the vertical spacing. (which is kinda bad, as the whole thing shifts up and down if the user uses a titlegraphic with not the exact dimensions, making the top logo disappear).

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Is there a way to generate a colored box on the side which overlaps the titlegraphics?!

Example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{der Autor}
\title{Titel der Präsentation}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5.5cm]{sample.eps}}
\subtitle{Unteritel der Präsentation}
%\usetheme{FHNW}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{FHNW}[1][]
{
\vskip -0.3cm
\hskip -0.7cm
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{fhnw_de.eps}}
\insertlogo

\vspace{0.5cm}
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hspace{-1.2cm}
\inserttitlegraphic
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
 [image: screenshot]

Comment: Which theme(s) are you using? Exactly where exactly do you want the elements (the logos and the colored box)? Can you please compose a little sample document showing the relevant settings and add it as an edit to your question?

Comment: Could you provide a MWE (Minimum Working Example) of the code you have used so far?

Comment: @performant without the MWE it's really hard to provide effective help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Gonzalo. I've added the code - it's lacking the images though

Comment: @performant Not anymore :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility; the key is to use `beamercolorbox`es to fix the position for the elements:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{187,224,227}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,102,0}

\setbeamercolor{graphbg}{fg=blue,bg=myblue}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{FHNW}[1][]
{%
\vfill
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{cat}}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=0.5em,left,ht=0.6cm,dp=0.2cm]{}
\insertlogo
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip8pt
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0em,left]{}
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip12pt
\hspace*{-0.25\beamer@leftmargin}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimexpr\textwidth+1.5\beamer@rightmargin\relax,sep=0em,left,rightskip=3em,ht=5cm,dp=0.5cm]{graphbg}
\parbox[t]{30pt}{\textcolor{myorange}{\rule[6pt]{30pt}{4cm}}}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\inserttitlegraphic}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
}
\makeatother

\author{der Autor}
\title{Titel der Präsentation}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{cat}}
\subtitle{Unteritel der Präsentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wasn't sure about the desired positioning for the other information (author, institution, etc.), but you can easily adapt my example code to put those elements at the desired location.

On a side note, there's no need to load `graphicx` (since `beamer` internally loads it); also, since `amssymb` internally loads `amsfonts`, you can only load the former.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, kind sir!